# Best practice C# REST API

Tags: c#, .net, rest, asp.net-core-webapi

We are developing a REST API and we're allowing all four of the standard verbs. In the case of an POST/PUT
what is better in best practice c# rest api.

this is my Model

```
public class UserModel
{
    public Int64 ID { get; set; }
    [Display(Name ="First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Address { get; set; }
    [Display(Name="User Name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [Display(Name ="Added Date")]
    public DateTime AddedDate { get; set; }
}
```

**Exemple 1**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateEditUser(UserModel model)
{
    if (model.ID == 0)
    {
        User userEntity = new User
        {
           //....
         }
   }
}
```

**Exemple 2**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateEditUser(int id,UserModel model)
{
    if (id == 0)
    {
        User userEntity = new User
        {
            //.....
         }
     }
 }
```

what is the better Exemple 1 Or Exemple 2

Comment: https://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html should answer that

Comment: Have you tried them both? I don't think Example 2 will work by default because you have two parameters.

Comment: I would use `HTTPPUT` for example 2, easier to lookup target and do an update...if that is what example 2 is supposed to do.

Comment: Best practise would be your first example. Within the model you can define [Model validations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-3.1) and detect if the model is valid based on your criteria. If it does or doesn't you can show the appropriate message based on those actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According the REST guidelines (https://github.com/microsoft/api-guidelines/blob/vNext/Guidelines.md)

> **PUT**: Replace an object, or create a named object, when applicable
>
> **POST**: Create a new object based on the data provided, or submit a command
>
> **PATCH**: Apply a partial update to an object

In your case is it better to split the endpoints into a **POST** and **PUT**.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateUser(UserModel model) 
{
    userService.Create(model);
    return...
}

[HttpPut]
public ActionResult EditUser(UserModel model)
{
    userService.Update(model);
    return...
}
```

Comment: so I don't need to put int id in methode because i have the Id in my Model ??

Comment: For the create you don't need the id, because the id would typically be generated somewhere else to ensure that it's unique.

For the edit/update your model would contain the needed id, which will be returned to you when you did the read/get operation.

Comment: oky but in the same time I have already the id inside The model for this reason i told I don't need the id int in the input methode when i have the model